# jquery mobile ajax jsonp request does not pass second get url parameter anymore

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jsonp, url-parameters

Sorry for not being precise enough in my first version of the post/ here is an updated post with sample code

i am using jquery 1.6.4 and jquery mobile 1.0rc2/ i first have to admit that i am relatively new to jquery mobile/ i built several web apps which run without bigger problems yet/ all of a sudden from the one second to the next a couple of my app where broken/ looking closer at the problem revealed that those apps where all apps which ingest a json from a api which i retreive by a ajax jsonp request/ the get url contains 2 parameters after the ? ?auth_token & meta_prefix (plus the autogenerated jquery callback parameter)/ the problem seems to be that jquery does not pass the second parameter anymore/ it just deleted it before sending the request/ this is true for all the broken web apps/ has anyone an idea what might have changed?

The url in the request looks like this :
http://myURL?auth_token=myToken&meta_prefix=m_
the url that is sent looks like this however:
http://myURL?auth_token=myToken&callback=jQuery16308668286966791752_1322474687995

the strange thing is that when i change the parameter name to metaprefix instead of meta_prefix it sends it  however this time puts the parameter after the callback. what is going on here?

any help is greatly appreciated

below is the code i am using for the call

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myURL?auth_token=myToken&meta_prefix=m_',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: true, // i need this to be set to true because otherwise jquery adds a cache parameter which the api i am using has problems with
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#list1').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
            listItems = $('#list1').find('ul');
            $.each(data, function(key) {
                html += '<p>From: '+data.array[key].m_total_resources+'</p>';
                listItems.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
            });
            // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
            $('#list1 ul').listview();
        }
    });
})
```

I was playing around a little more with this problem and what i found was that using another api just for testing like for instance the apple search api http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=album  i am not able to replicate that second parameter problem/ probably it is my lack of understanding but could the api play a role in this error? or the url the parameters are appended to? if i put the url in the browser I get the responds i am expecting; 
what is so frustrating is that everything worked just fine the days before yesterday

cheers

macs

Comment: Can you please add some code that we can look at to diagnose the problem - HTML / JavaScript would be good ..

Comment: Please don't create multiple accounts on the system. I've merged your two accounts into the one with the questions.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the inconvenience but I was not aware that i've created two accounts/ 
the problem i reported above is solved/ it was indeed a problem of the api/ they say they implemented some ajax functions which stopped the api from responding to certain parameters/ to be honest i was a bit confused about that/ i thought that what one can see in the live httpheaders  plugin  of firefox is showing the get requests that has actually ben sent/ however based on the problem i had it seems that it is more what the responding api things it has been sent/ is that correct in any way?